# Backbone, Coffeescript - passing function as a callback in AJAX

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript

In my Backbone View, I have two methods, one does a simple AJAX call, and the other is the callback function I want to run. I want to call the AJAX method with the callback function as its parameter.

```
call_ajax_function: =>
  @get_stuff(@my_callback)

get_stuff: (callback_function) =>
  $.ajax
    url:'get_something'
    success: =>
      callback_function

my_callback: =>
  console.log "hello"
```

But I don't think "my_callback" is getting called. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to invoke your function, try changing

```
get_stuff: (callback_function) =>
  $.ajax
    url:'get_something'
    success: =>
      callback_function
```

to

```
get_stuff: (callback_function) ->
  $.ajax
    url:'get_something'
    success: (data) => #success takes arguments, pass them thru
      callback_function(data)
```

I **think** you don't need to pass the argument into `get_stuff` like you are doing.  So I think this should work

```
get_stuff: ->
  $.ajax
    url:'get_something'
    success: (data) => 
      @callback_function(data)
```

Plus, it should have the advantage that the context of the callback will be the instance, i.e. within the callback execution `@` will be the correct instance.

If you want to specify the callback method dynamically, AND you want to specify the scope on which that method executes, you need to use `call` like so

```
get_stuff: (onSuccess)->
      $.ajax
        url:'get_something'
        success: (data) => 
          onSuccess.call @, data
```

As a note, when defining methods on a class, I don't thing `=>` is buying you anything.  Use `->` for those methods.  Use `=>` when you want to look the context into an anonymous function.

Comment: You're correct you can do `@callback_function()` within `success` as long as you do the `=>` to maintain scope, just to clarify :)

Comment: @JackFranklin thanx.  What about my final assertion regarding the use of `=>` for instance methods?

Comment: If you keep the fat arrow `=>` on `get_stuff` though, you could just do `success: @callback_function`. So `get_stuff: => $.ajax url: 'url', success: @callback_function`.